# How do I get empty fields in SOLR indexed for a schemaless collection?

Tags: indexing, solr, field, schemaless

How do I get empty fields in SOLR indexed? I am using solr 7.2.0

I am using schemaless SOLR to try to index everything as string, but for files with empty fields, those fields do not get indexed. Is there a way to get them to show up?

```
col1,col2,col3
a,,1
d,e,
g,h,3
```

for example column 1 shows up as

```
{
"col1":"a",
"col3":"1",
}
```

I'm trying to also get col2 to show up. 
in my solrconfig.xml i have this

```
  <dynamicField name="*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" default="" />
```

and I have any traces of the remove-blank processor removed from my config. I've reloaded and deleted/recreated by collection multiple times. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV import module [has its own option](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#csv-update-parameters) to keep empty fields - `f.<field name>.keepEmpty=true`.

If you don't give that option, the CSV handler will never give the empty field value to the next step in your indexing process.

Giving `f.col2.keepEmpty=True` as an URL argument should at least give you a better starting point.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this for all columns instead of just selected columns since my collection is schemaless?

Comment: Try just `f.keepEmpty` or just `keepEmpty`. Usually the field part is optional, and the docs say that as well -- _This parameter can be global or per-field._

Answer (score 0):

maybe preprocess your csv file like this:

```
s/,,/, ,/g
```

That is, add an space between both commas (you will have to specially deal with the last value differntly though, there is a regex for that).

And then try again. Right now solr is reading the value as non existant, making it a space has more chances to make it through, and would not change search results (if you don't have some crazy analysis chains)